# How do I make requests work with the same site three times?

Tags: python, python-requests

There is one site. And there are three programs that work the same way, that is, they send similar requests to the server. On the server, there is a limit of 1 request with 1 IP in 0.5 seconds, otherwise a stub image will appear. How can I make requests bypass this restriction? Is it possible to adjust the IP in Python requests? I tried to change the user-agent and the name of the sessions, but every now and then, three programs interfered with each other and this very stub came out.

Comment: Either spin 3 copies of your applications over 3 instances with different IPs or rate-limit your application to not send requests at higher frequency than 2/sec

Comment: how do I change my IP?

Comment: That's not an option (even if it's possible, it will take longer than 0.5 a sec so it won't really help you).

Comment: if you send a request from another IP, then there will be no stub, the question is how to change this IP?

Comment: You can change IP using `proxies` parameter.

Comment: Check this answer to change the IP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447709/python-requests-change-ip-address#answer-63095099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypass rate limit for requests.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657270/bypass-rate-limit-for-requests-get)

Comment: how do I import from a free proxy site now?